# Flutter camera plugin not importing/useable

Tags: dart, flutter

I am getting the following error when beginning to implement the [camera plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/camera#-readme-tab-) on my flutter app:

```
  [VERBOSE-2:dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
  MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method init on channel plugins.flutter.io/camera)
  #0      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:153:7)
  <asynchronous suspension>
  #1      _channel (package:camera/camera.dart:7:5)
  #2      _channel (package:camera/camera.dart:6:21)
  #3      availableCameras (package:camera/camera.dart:42:41)
  <asynchronous suspension>
  #4      main (file:///Users/waynerumble/Desktop/scott_and_viki/lib/main.dart:10:19)
  <asynchronous suspension>
  #5      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:279:19)
  #6      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:165:12)
  [VERBOSE-2:dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
  MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method list on channel plugins.flutter.io/camera)
  #0      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:153:7)
  <asynchronous suspension>
  #1      availableCameras (package:camera/camera.dart:42:50)
  <asynchronous suspension>
  #2      main (file:///Users/waynerumble/Desktop/scott_and_viki/lib/main.dart:10:19)
  <asynchronous suspension>
  #3      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:279:19)
  #4      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:165:12)
```

The error doesn't occur until i start using the plugin itself, i.e. if i replace `Future<null> main() etc` with `void main() => runApp(new App());` the app runs fine. I've followed install instructions from the link provided and tried pasting in all the example incode in place of mine but still get the errors

My main.dart:

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import 'Localisations.dart';
  import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
  import 'dart:async';
  import 'package:camera/camera.dart';

  List<CameraDescription> cameras;

  Future<Null> main() async {
    cameras = await availableCameras();
    runApp(new App());
  }

  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      var statusBarHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;
      var titleText = new Text(Localize.of(context).appTitle,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: new TextStyle(fontFamily: 'CallingAngelsPersonalUse',
          fontSize: 50.0,
          color: Colors.black)
      );
      var backgroundImage = new BoxDecoration(
          image: new DecorationImage(
           image: new AssetImage('assets/background.png'),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      );

      var mainContainer = new Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: statusBarHeight),
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: backgroundImage,
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
                new Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                  child: titleText
            )
          ],
        ),

      );

      return new Scaffold(
        body: mainContainer,
      );
    }
  }

  class App extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return new MaterialApp(
        onGenerateTitle: (BuildContext context) => Localize.of(context).appTitle,
        localizationsDelegates: [
          const LocalizeDelegate(),
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        ],
        supportedLocales: [
          const Locale('en', '')
        ],
        home: new MyApp(),
      );
    }
  }
```

My pubspec.yml:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  camera: ^0.1.2
  path_provider: ^0.4.0
  flutter_localizations:
      sdk: flutter
```

This is my first real flutter app so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Assuming Android, as you don't specify. Has the android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java file been created?

Comment: I was getting the error on both simulators, the GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java file exists in `android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/io.flutter.plugins`

Comment: Can you see the following line in that file?     `CameraPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.camera.CameraPlugin"));`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First check your app.build `minSdkVersion`. Make sure `minSdkVersion` is `21`.

```
minSdkVersion 21
```

Here is my code example:

```
List<CameraDescription> cameras = [];
main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  try {
    cameras = await availableCameras();

  } on CameraException catch (e) {
   logError(e.code, e.description);
  }
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: still getting error - Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method availableCameras on channel plugins.flutter.io/camera)

Comment: run flutter clean and re run flutter run command

Answer (score 0):

Despite manually adding the dependency to `pubspec.yaml` and running `flutter pub get`, what worked for me was running

```
flutter pub add camera
```

followed by

```
flutter pub get
```

and finally adding

```
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
```

in main.dart (or the dart file where the error is happening). These are from the [installation instructions](https://pub.dev/packages/camera/install).

Answer (score 0):

1. For android, make sure your midSdkVersion parameter is 21 or higher,
2. if your project minSdkVersion == flutter.minSdkVersion
3. edit .../packages/flutter_tools/gradle/src/main/groovy/flutter.groovy, change minSdkVersion value to 21 or higher

[Take a picture using the camera](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/plugins/picture-using-camera)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).